# Limesurvey - password not hashing after transferring installation

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, encryption, limesurvey

I have just managed to get my Limesurvey installation transferred to a new server, logged in and everything appears to be working as normal. Well almost everything..

There is some issues with the password encryption, the passwords are not working in there regular format. I see they are saved in the Database in hashed bytea form (eg. "582f443f5477a4d6f50f33c14edb1abcbf2048eccc130f430caj4s8hp6e54cdd"). If I copy paste this into the password box I can log in but it fails if I enter the regular/ non encrypted password.

Not sure how to fix this.. any ideas? I see LS uses sha 256 hashing but for some reason the user entered password is not being hashed before comparing with the stored DB value.

I'm running LS version 2.00+ on Apache 2.2 with PHP 5.4, with a Postgres 9.1 DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just figured out.. It was the Postgres database that I hadn't set up correctly.. I had to define the Variable 'bytea_output' = escape and I also replicated the Privileges that were on the old DB.